# What is the simplest syntax of the if-else statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2)   return false ;
endgame();   return true;
```

this is the some JavaScript code which I'm not really understand, the code are using the simplest way to write the if-else statement but it makes me confuse about it, because how could it having three else with a same condition? the way that I interpret is

```
if(b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {return false} else {endgame()} else {return true}
```

but I feel weird with this so I asked this question, I just want to know the correct syntax of this code. I think it may be my misunderstood of the code.

Comment: You cannot have two `else` clauses; just one.

Comment: @Pointy if you don't count `else if` as a `else` clause :)

Comment: @Jite well `else if` is not a clause at all; it's an else followed by the start of a new `if` statement. Languages differ in that regard, and JavaScript is like the C family of languages that don't have an `elseif` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for both explanation ! that was my big misunderstood.... Thanks for helping me!

Comment: All good, and I do know the difference, but for a person who asks a question as above, it might be hard to grasp the difference when told that you can only have one `else` when you can have as many `else if` as you wish. Semantics might be important, but sometimes it might confuse too.

Comment: yap, the code only having one condition so there is no else-if clause in the code, so it makes me feels like there was two else clause in the code, and it shouldn't have two else clause with a single condition.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a part of a function, because of the `return` statements. You get only one condition with a return statement and no else parts, because there are no one.

```
if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {
    return false;
}
endgame();
return true;
```

Comment: ...wow that was a big misunderstood of the code ! Thanks for the correct explanation !